# How to do a case insensitive match for command line arguments in scala?

Tags: scala, command-line-interface, scopt

I'm working on a command line tool written in Scala which is executed as:

```
sbt "run --customerAccount 1234567"
```

Now, I wish to make this flexible to accept `"--CUSTOMERACCOUNT"` or `--cUsToMerAccount` or `--customerACCOUNT` ...you get the drift

Here's what the code looks like:

```
lazy val OptionsParser: OptionParser[Args] = new scopt.OptionParser[Args]("scopt") {
    head(
      "XML Generator",
      "Creates XML for testing"
    )
    help("help").text(s"Prints this usage message. $envUsage")

    opt[String]('c', "customerAccount")
      .text("Required: Please provide customer account number as -c 12334 or --customerAccount 12334")
      .required()
      .action { (cust, args) =>
        assert(cust.nonEmpty, "cust is REQUIRED!!")
        args.copy(cust = cust)
      }
}
```

I assume the `opt[String]('c', "customerAccount")` does the pattern matching from the command line and will match with "customerAccount" - how do I get this to match with `"--CUSTOMERACCOUNT"` or `--cUsToMerAccount` or `--customerACCOUNT`? What exactly does the `args.copy (cust = cust)` do?

I apologize if the questions seem too basic. I'm incredibly new to Scala, have worked in Java and Python earlier so sometimes I find the syntax a little hard to understand as well.

Comment: Your question seems to be related to scopt library rather to scala in general, I would start with scopt documentation to see if it support what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd normally be parsing the args with code like:

```
OptionsParser.parse(args, Args())
```

So if you want case-insensitivity, probably the easiest way is to canonicalize the case of `args` with something like

```
val canonicalized = args.map(_.toLowerCase)

OptionsParser.parse(canonicalized, Args())
```

Or, if you for instance wanted to only canonicalize args starting with `--` and before a bare `--`:

```
val canonicalized =
  args.foldLeft(false -> List.empty[String]) { (state, arg) =>
    val (afterDashes, result) = state
    if (afterDashes) true -> (arg :: result)  // pass through unchanged
    else {
      if (arg == "==") true -> (arg :: result) // move to afterDash state & pass through
      else {
        if (arg.startsWith("--")) false -> (arg.toLowerCase :: result)
        else false -> (arg :: result) // pass through unchanged
      }
    }
  }
  ._2    // Extract the result
  .reverse // Reverse it back into the original order (if building up a sequence, your first choice should be to build a list in reversed order and reverse at the end)

  OptionsParser.parse(canonicalized, Args())
```

Re the second question, since `Args` is (almost certainly) a `case class`, it has a `copy` method which constructs a new object with (most likely, depending on usage) different values for its fields.  So

```
 args.copy(cust = cust)
```

creates a new `Args` object, where:

- the value of the `cust` field in that object is the value of the `cust` variable in that block (this is basically a somewhat clever hack that works with named method arguments)
- every other field's value is taken from `args`

Comment: This is immensely helpful, thank you kind sir! I got confused with `cust = cust` since they both look and imply the same at first glance. Coming from a java background I would have preferred `this.cust = cust` for better readability.

I think I will work with caconicalizing the case of `args` and see how that builds up! Thanks a million for your answer! :)